# UITableViewRowAnimation is ignored

Tags: ios, animation, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my table. The data in my table is sorted according to the timestamp in the ascending order (latest message at the bottom). More data is loaded via "infinite scroll" to the top: e.g. when user scrolls past the top, more messages are loaded. My `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` is defined as usual, as recommended in the apple documentation: new rows are inserted via

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"insertion at row %d", newIndexPath.row);
            [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            break;
```

Now here is my problem: when new rows are inserted, they are always animated as sliding "down". On the infinite scroll upwards it looks bad. 
That happens regardless of whether I pass `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`, `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` or `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` as the parameter - that option seems to be ignored entirely.

Any ideas how to animate the table properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I've figured it out.

WWDC 2011 talk "Advanced Table View Techniques" explicitly says that UITableViewRowAnimationNone does not mean no animation (:

As if it made sense.

The animation parameter merely defines *how* the row is inserted into the space (e.g. slide from the right/left/etc), the transitions to *create* that space are animated regardless of what user wants.

So yeah, there is *no* way to insert/delete/refresh individual cells, and `reloadData` is the way to go. I love you, Apple.

Now according to many answers on stackoverflow there is also no way to insert content at the top of the table without changing the current view (e.g. seemlessly insert stuff with no changes to what user sees at all). The best one can do is to change the `contentOffset` after the new data have arrived.

Comment: There is no WWDC 2011 talk titled "Advanced Table View Techniques". Did you mean "UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks"? If not, could you link to the one you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @trss Sorry I'm really not sure anymore, haven't done iOS for a while. Maybe it's the one you're referring to.

Answer (score 13):

Please try as below.

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO]; // reset to original value
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was getting an ugly animation when inserting new sections into my table view, and this has fixed it (lifesaver).

Comment: You forgot [CATransaction begin] and commit... ?

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to disable insert/delete cells animation.

```
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [_tableView beginUpdates];

    [_table insertCell...];
    [_table removeCell...]

    [_table endUpdates];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

It's perfectly doing work.

Comment: Honestly a nice hack for a ridiculous over-complication.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 7.0, you can wrap the code in a `performWithoutAnimation:` block, like so:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    [self.tableView endUpdates];
                }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you breaking the data into sections? If you are, check your implementation of `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` as new section inserts will be animated with the animation types used in that method, not `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`.