# UITableViewRowAnimationNone - behaving as UITableViewRowAnimation(Top/Bottom)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, caanimation

I have set the row insertion with the following code. I am only using `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` when inserting and deleting the rows, but sometimes ,as you can see in the gif below, the row animates in from the top or bottom. For the most part it doesn't animate, as I want it, but sometimes it animates on insertion and deletion. I am not talking about the table view expanding to show the inserted cell, I mean the cell appears to be sliding in from the bottom or top.

[image]

Here is the method that controls the insertion animation:

```
- (void)contentHeaderFooterView:(NFContentHeaderFooterView *)headerFooterView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)section{

    NSIndexPath *pathToAdd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pathToAdd] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

And here is the method that controls the deletion animation.

```
- (void)contentHeaderFooterView:(NFContentHeaderFooterView *)headerFooterView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)section{

    NSIndexPath *pathToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: Same issue, seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with table updates not performing the animation I gave it directly. I can't say for sure why, but one thing I can suggest is, instead of doing a specific row deletion between begin/endUpdates, you can just to a hard reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352789/577237

Reposted since it's brief:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    [self.tableView endUpdates];
                }];
```

Note that this is iOS 7.0+